# Xamarin ContentPage implicit style

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin

I'm trying to globally change the background of all ContentPage controls in my app by defining an implicit style in App.xaml that sets BackgroundColor property.

While implicit styles in Xamarin seem to work at least for Buttons (personally verified), it doesn't seem to work for ContentPages. Setting the style explicitly via Style="{StaticResource PageStyle}" works just fine. However when I remove the x:Key attribute from the style in App.xaml to make it implicit, style doesn't affect ContentPage controls.

Am I missing something or have I found a bug in Xamarin.

PS: I've only tested this on Android. Not sure how it will behave on iOS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is a bug as what you had mentioned [[ref](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/34798/how-to-add-global-background-color-style)].
The article also stated another workaround.